# 3D marker symbol export problem (ArcGIS 10.2)

Tags: arcgis-10.2, 3d, 3d-analyst, arcscene, web-scene

I am trying to create a webscene.  I have a TIN and a point layer that is 3d enabled (point z).  I added a 3d symbol marker to the point layer in ArcScene .  When I use the "export to 3d web scene" tool in 3d Analyst, the TIN exports fine, but i get an error message for my point layer: "Layer: restricted symbology will be ignored".  Again, I read the manual on how to create a webscene and it mentions that the layer has to be 3d enabled (which I assume is the "point z" attribute) and that the symbology has to be a 3d marker symbol (where I am using the 3d residential style reference).   I did both (I think).

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful but check out this [ArcGIS help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s500000013000000) at the bottom it discusses enabling 3d layer properties.